# Step by step explanation of this combinatorics solution

Tags: combinatorics

$6$ people are to be divided into $(a)$ two groups of three or $(b)$ into three groups of two.

For $(a)$ I solved for $6\choose3$, and for $(b)$, $6\choose2$$\cdot$$4\choose2$.

But apparently for $(a$), according to the text book solution, I'm supposed to do $6\choose3$$:2!$, and for $(b)$ it's $[$$6\choose2$$\cdot$$4\choose2$$]$$:3!$.

My question is, why are these divisions necessary?

Comment: The answer has to be reduced from 6! by the number of elements you are taking at a time.

Comment: Well, I wanted to know why...

Comment: There was a similar question today and I wrote a solution there for the general case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151081/there-are-10-students-in-the-class-how-many-ways-can-we-split-them-into-group/3151180#3151180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of ambiguity in how the question is phrased in regards to whether or not which group is which is relevant.  The interpretation that you took was that it is while the interpretation that the book went with was that it wasn't.

Suppose our persons are labeled $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and our groups are colored $\color{red}{red}$ and $\color{blue}{blue}$.

To divide our people into two groups of three, your logic went something like "Pick which three people are in the red group and the rest will be in the blue group.  One possible outcome might have looked like this: $(\color{red}{1~2~3})~(\color{blue}{4~5~6})$ while a *different* outcome might have been $(\color{red}{4~5~6})~(\color{blue}{1~2~3})$.

That is a perfectly acceptable interpretation of the problem in many situations.  The problem did not make it clear that the groups are to be considered indistinguishable.  For example, if the red team is going to be going to go play outside while the blue team is going to be forced to practice more math problems, the scenario where $1,2,3$ are all in the team playing outside is going to give them a very different experience than if they had been the group to need to study more math.

The interpretation that the book used however is that these outcomes are actually "indistinguishable" and so the only thing that matters is *who* is on the same team as one another, not specifically *which* label that team gets.  In such a situation you see that $(\color{red}{1~2~3})~(\color{blue}{4~5~6})$ and $(\color{red}{4~5~6})~(\color{blue}{1~2~3})$ really represent the same outcomes since in both scenarios the teammates for each person is the same from each person's perspective.  This would occur for example if both teams were needing to study more math and were grouping together to solve problems in a group, or if both teams were going to play street hockey against each other or something.  Their experiences won't be changed based on which team they were on, only by who they are on a team with.

---

The logic to arrive at the answer for where the teams are considered indistinguishable used by the book relied on "division by symmetry" and is something that I prefer to avoid when possible.  An alternate argument for how to arrive at the answers is to do the following:

- Arbitrarily assign an order to the children.  For example, by age.
- Find the person who is youngest.
- Now, count how many ways there are to choose two other people to be on the youngest player's team.

Note, these first two steps do not actually affect our count in any way.  There is only one way to select the youngest person.

That gives an answer of $\binom{5}{2}$, which you will find is precisely $\binom{6}{3}/2$

Similarly, for the second part of the problem, we can repeat this where after the first group is set, find who is youngest from those remaining and then choose *their* teammates as well, giving a total of $\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1}$ which you'll find is equal to $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}/3!$

Answer (score 1):

(a) If you pick $A$, $B$, $C$ to form a group and leave $D$, $E$, $F$ to form the other group, you will end up with the same grouping by picking $D$, $E$, $F$ to form a group and leaving $A$, $B$, $C$ to form the other group. So you have double counted.

(b) is similar.

Comment: Ok, great, I get what you're saying. But would mind to elaborate a bit more? I'm self-taught, so it would be much appreciated if you helped me build a more intuitive idea of why.

Answer (score 0):

Here a general solution for grouping $N$ *distinguishable* items into $r$ groups of size $K$ (which means $N = K\cdot r$):

- all possible arrangements of $N$ items: $\color{blue}{N!}$

Now, divide the places for  the arrangements in $r$ blocks of $K$ consecutive items:

- $\underbrace{(1 \ldots K)(K+1 \; \ldots 2K) \ldots (N-K+ 1 \; \ldots N)}_{r \: blocks = r\: groups}$

So, you can see that a given grouping into groups of size $K$ is achieved by several arrangements as follows:

- Rearranging the $r$ groups among each other and rearranging the items within the groups of $K$ items: $\color{blue}{r! \cdot (K!)^r}$

So, you get as a general formula
$$\frac{\color{blue}{N!}}{\color{blue}{r! \cdot (K!)^r}}$$

Comment: You should probably include the word *distinguishable* or *indistinguishable* when referring to this or the related formulae for the other cases to make it clear which formula is used for which scenario.  A different formula exists for when the groups are distinguishable vs indistinguishable as well as for when the items are distinguishable vs indistinguishable.

Comment: @JMoravitz : Yes. This makes it more explicit although the reasoning shows that I deal with distinguishable items.

Comment: I was referring more specifically to adding clarification to the phrase "*...into $r$ indistinguishable groups of size...*" as this is where the OP's confusion lied.